# Why is it everytime I click my button the tab goes back to it's original place?

Tags: html, jquery-ui

I'm having a problems, everytime I click my `btn_register` the tab goes back to Login. Why is this?

Here's my JAVASCRIPT Code:

```
$(function() {
        $("input:submit").button();
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    });
```

Here's my HTML Code:

```
<section id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#login">Login</a></li>
    <li><a href="#register">Register</a></li>
</ul>
<article id="login">
    <p>
        <form>
            <input type="submit" id="btn_login">
        </form>
    </p>
</article>
<article id="register">
        <form>
            <input type="submit" id="btn_register">
        </form>
    </p>
</article>
```

Comment: Looks like you haven't told it to do anything on the pressing of submit/register.

Answer (score 1):

It's because JQuery doesn't know which input:submit you are referring to. [Check this out for help](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/determining-which-of-two-submit-buttons-were-clicked-in-a-single-form)

Comment: so best solution is to separate them?

Answer (score 1):

depends what you're trying to do, but it is because I am assuming this is on the login page? I believe by default, when you have a input type submit, it will try to send the form to the current page. If it is not a form, and just a button, I recommend you use the button tag instead:

```
<button id='btn_register'>Register</button>
```

On some browsers, the button tag will not do anything, but it may still refresh the page. to stop this behavior, append this to your code:

```
$('#btn_register').on('click',function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  //do whatever you want to here        
});
```

if the register button is just suppose to be a link that will go to another page, I suggest using the anchor tag instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
        $("#btn_login").button();
    $("#btn_register").button();
```

I change my code to this. and it works